# Unable to start AI Suite 3 after updating ("Invalid class string, ProgID: AsusFanControlService.FanControlManager")

Tags: asus

After updating *Asus AI Suite* (from version *2.01.12* to *3.01.10*), it is impossible to start it.

Nothing happens when I launch AI Suite and I get the following message when the PC starts up:

```
Invalid class string, ProgID:
"AsusFanControlService.FanControlManager"
```

The solutions I've found on the internet are not only dated, they don't work, at least for my version of *AI Suite* and on *Windows 11*.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, follow these steps.

1. **Uninstall your version of *AI Suite* using the dedicated uninstaller found on the Asus website**

I made the mistake of uninstalling it via the *Windows Control Panel* (*Programs* > *Programs and Features*), and not with the *AI Suite* dedicated uninstaller.
Then, once *AI Suite 3* had been reinstalled, the following message appeared every time Windows started up:

```
Invalid class string, ProgID:
"AsusFanControlService.FanControlManager"
```

To remedy this, you first need to delete the "*AsusFanControlService*" service from the Windows registry.
To do this:

- type "*regedit*" in the Windows search bar
- search (Ctrl + F) for the "*AsusFanControlService*" service

  - for me, it was in: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\AsusFanControlService*

> You will notice in passing that the "*Path*" entry has the value (at least in my case): "*C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AsusFanControlService\2.01.12\AsusFanControlService.exe*".
>
> Since *AI Suite* has been uninstalled, the "*C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AsusFanControlService*" folder is empty, even after reinstalling *AI Suite 3* (this is the problem we will see later: *AI Suite 3* does not reinstall "*AsusFanControlService*"!). It is therefore quite normal that the "*AsusFanControlService*" service cannot be started because it no longer exists... Hence the message "*Invalid class string, ProgID: AsusFanControlService.FanControlManager*" which is displayed when Windows starts.

- right-click on the "*AsusFanControlService*" folder in the tree on the left and click on "*Delete*".

2. **Now that AI Suite is properly uninstalled, you can install the latest version (for me it's version "*3.01.10*")**

At this stage, *AI Suite 3* still does not launch.

The reason is as follows: "*AsusFanControlService*" has not been installed by the *AI Suite* installer (the "*C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AsusFanControlService*" folder does not exist (or is empty if you haven't deleted it manually)...).

3. **Here's the actual fix I suggest: manually install "*AsusFanControlService*"**

Run the following program located in the *AI Suite* ZIP file:

> */SW_ASUS_AISuite3_PPSU_EZ_SZ_TSD_W11_64_V30110_20220110R/PPSU_2.00.92/AppSetup/AsusFanCtrlSvc/Setup.exe*

> Now you have a "*C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AsusFanControlService*" folder with something in it!

Restart your PC.

4. **Voilà! You can now launch AI Suite 3!**

Enjoy!

Comment: Where did these instructions come from exactly? You quoted the meat and potatoes portion of the instructions I assume since you are quoting somebody

Comment: Hello Ramhound,
These instructions come from me alone.
I have tried to solve this problem in various ways and what I describe here is the method that has worked for me.
Quotations are not quotations. They are simply a way of formatting the text.